# What Account is used by Truffle as a Default?

Tags: truffle

I have the following outputs -

```
> eth.getStorageAt(con.address,0)
"0x00000000000000f07044ba718e8eb25850be0e534f9522018784be60043a984d"
> eth.getStorageAt(con.address,1)   
"0x00000000000000000000000046fb9a22689c4a4bfb494baeafbb8b2993725305"
> eth.getStorageAt(con.address,2)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
> con.buyer()
"0xf07044ba718e8eb25850be0e534f9522018784be"
> eth.coinbase
"0x46fb9a22689c4a4bfb494baeafbb8b2993725305"
> eth.defaultAccount
"0xf07044ba718e8eb25850be0e534f9522018784be"
>
```

Here is the contract -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract CollegeAdmin {
uint8 public studentAge=18;
uint16 public studentIncome=15000;
uint8 public studentScore=4;
uint8 public studentAttendance=96;
address public buyer;
address public owner;
event changedAge(uint age);

function CollegeAdmin() public {
owner = msg.sender;
}
function setAge(uint8 age) public {
buyer=msg.sender;
studentAge = age;
changedAge(age);
}

}
```

I expected the default account to be used and hence owner = defaultAccount which then is shown in slot 1 of the storage. But slot 1 has eth.coinbase. But when I run setAge, I find that the buyer it then set to eth.defaultAccount.

It seems to be truffle deploys under eth.coinbase and then the contract runs under eth.defaultAccount.

I tried changing truffle.js -

```
module.exports = {
   networks: {
   development: {
   host: "localhost",
   port: 8545,
   network_id: "*",
 gas: 4712388,
 from: "0xf07044ba718e8eb25850be0e534f9522018784be"
 }
}
};
```

This then gives a network error.

```
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Replacing Migrations...
  ... undefined
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful 
transactions manually.
```

This is I imagine related to eth.coinbase but geth does not let me change that.

Has anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify the creator of the contract directly in the deployment scripts

```
var MyContract = artifacts.require("MyContract");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(MyContract, { from: "0xACCOUNT" });
}
```